# Show calendar in messenger chatbot

Tags: java, webview, calendar, google-calendar-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I am making a chatbot to book appointments for different services, and I wanted to show a calendar in the chatbox for the user to choose the day as an alternative to writing it down.

I am using a JBOS-EAP-7.2 and the chatbot it's already up and running.

I am also using the library of Cliver/Racter from GitHub: "https://github.com/Clivern/Racter" to show some buttons, and send the messages.

I tried this, but I presume it'll open the calendar in another tab and I'll not be able to retrieve the date picked by the user. (haven't managed to make this work either).

```
button_message_tpl.setRecipientId(senderId);
button_message_tpl.setMessageText("Choose a date");
button_message_tpl.setButton("web_url", "Open calendar", urlCalendar, "");
platform.getBaseSender().send(button_message_tpl);
```

I was looking for some way to introduce a Google Calendar API in the chatbox, in a similar way, but I am not finding any useful information about webviews in Messenger, apart from chatfuel and similar services which I can't use.

Which way may be better for me to show a calendar in the chatbox and be able to retrieve the date clicked by the user? If possible using a Google Calendar API.